# Elasticsearch edge_ngram token_chars whitespace

Tags: elasticsearch, token, n-gram

Can somebody tell me please how works Elasticsearch **edge_ngram** **token_chars whitespace**? Token_chars should define signs which will be included in tokens. So if I use `token_chars: ['letter', 'digit', 'whitespace']` what it means in context of the phrase "2 red foxes"? As I understand it will produce tokens in this way **['2', '2 ', '2 r', '2 re', '2 red']**. Am I right the tokens are not splited on spaces but spaces will be included to tokens? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you are right but it also depends on `min_gram` and `max_gram` params values.

Take a look below.

### Example 1.

`min_gram = 2` and `max_gram = 10`

#### Mapping

```
PUT /so54090009
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "whitespace"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Analyze

```
POST /so54090009/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "2 red foxes"
}
```

#### Response

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "2 ",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "2 r",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "2 re",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "2 red",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "2 red ",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "2 red f",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "token": "2 red fo",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 6
    },
    {
      "token": "2 red fox",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 7
    },
    {
      "token": "2 red foxe",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 8
    }
  ]
}
```

### Example 2.

`min_gram = 1` and `max_gram = 5`

#### Mapping

```
PUT /so54090009
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 5,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "whitespace"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Analyze

```
POST /so54090009/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "2 red foxes"
}
```

#### Response

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "2",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "2 ",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "2 r",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "2 re",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "2 red",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand min and max grams. One thing I am not sure about is where is the token EDGE of edge_ngram if it is not whitespace.

Comment: As stated in [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html#_configuration_17): _Character classes that should be included in a token. Elasticsearch will split on characters that don’t belong to the classes specified. Defaults to `[]` (keep all characters)._ So if you select `['letter', 'digit', 'whitespace']` then `punctuation` and `symbol` chars will be marking edges. Did I explain enough?